# Href "#" tag not working in Chrome

Tags: html

I'm working on a free template "**[ritmo](http://dsathemes.com/html/ritmo/light/slider/index.html#video)**" but facing a issue that href # tags are not working in chrome but working in firefox

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a id="GoToHome" class="selected-nav" href="#intro">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="GoToFeatures" href="#features">Features</a></li>
<li><a id="GoToVideo" href="#video">Video</a></li>
<li><a id="GoToTestimonials" href="#testimonials-rotator">Testimonials</a></li> 
<li><a id="GoToFAQ" href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a id="GoToSubscribe" href="#newsletter">Subscribe</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the target section

```
<section id="features"> .... </section>
```

is there any issue with css display propert? I've tried multiple solutions but not works for me, here is some link of them [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654244/chrome-bug-or-coding-error-anchor-id-links-within-destination-page-not-working), and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414136/anchor-tags-not-working-in-chrome)

or can we say that it is due to some kind of restriction on href tag by java script on page?

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: Where is your Javascript code?

Comment: @Barmar it doesnot need any javascript code bcz href will directly go to `#url` part

Comment: Then why did you tag this javascript and jquery?

Comment: its working..check https://jsfiddle.net/6fkaLbmp/

Comment: @debin, jsfiddle is served under HTML5 doctype, so yes it should work there. We don't know that the OP is using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Roamer-1888: i'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Barmar: i used that tag because i think we can solve it using javascript if possible, otherwise there is no use of javascript

Comment: Under HTML5, Chrome should be working the same as FF. Sounds like Chrome has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute in the `a` tag should point to another `a` tag with the `name` attribute set:

```
<a id="GoToFeatures" href="#features">Features</a>
```

points to:

```
<a name="features">    
  enter code here`<section id="features"> .... </section> 
</a>
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Counter-example: [http://php.net/mysql_query#function.mysql-query-refsynopsisdiv](http://php.net/mysql_query#function.mysql-query-refsynopsisdiv)

Comment: The `name` attribute is not supported in HTML5, instead the `id` is to be used.

Comment: The name attribute most certainly is supported in HTML5, but there's an order of precedence. First the "fragment" algorithm looks for the first element (of any type) with an **ID** exactly equal to fragid; then for an `<a>` element that has a **name** attribute whose value is exactly equal to fragid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not expert Programmer. But I had the same issue with chrome, which solved with this piece of code. worked like a charm. Once Again Stack overflow gave me the results. My favorite site.
code:

```
                                         $(function() {
   $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
       var target = $(this.hash);
       target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top
         }, 1000);
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
 });
```